# Wordpress post loop first in line

Tags: css, wordpress, loops

I placed my post loop in a sidebar div.
I was wondering if there was any way to tell the code to affect CSS3 only on the 1st item of the loop?

Considering that there are going to be more posts added I can't go with post ID.

Like having a loop of 6 posts and being able to increase the size of the 1st post or any other CSS3 function.

Comment: its a regular <li> loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like

```
ul li:first-child
```

is doing the trick :)

i hope this might help someone in the future, sorry for taking everyones time :/

Answer (score 0):

To select the first element in css you can use `:first-child`

for example

```
li:first-child{
  background:#ff0000;
}


<ul>
  <li>im red</li>
  <li>im not</li>
</ul>
```